# How to deserialize an class into different class (in new namespace) using BinaryFormatter (C#)

Tags: c#, serialization, deserialization

I have a class `User` belong to `Authentication` namespace, as below:

```
namespace Authentication {
    public class User 
    {
       public string Name {get;set;}    
    }
}
```

I serialized an object of class User  using BinaryFormatter into byte[ ] and store it in database.

```
User usr = new User();
usr.Name = "myself";
var usrValue = convertObjectToByteArr(usr);
//then store usrValue into db.
```

After some time, class User has new property and moved to new namespace: `Authentication.Organization`

```
namespace Authentication.Organization{
    public class User 
    {
        public string Name {get;set;}

        public int Age {get;set;}
    }
}
```

**My question: How do I de-serialize the object of `previous` User into `current` User ?**

I'll hit exception: **`{"Unable to load type Authentication.User required for deserialization."}`** when I try to deserialize it:

```
byte[] prevUsrValue= (byte[])helper.getPreviousUserValue();//read from database

User previousUser = convertByteArrToObject(prevUsrValue) as User;
```

---

FYI, I am using these method to serialized and de-serialize:

```
//serialization
public static byte[] convertObjectToByteArr(object o)
{
    if (o != null)
    {
        System.IO.MemoryStream memoryStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
        System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter binaryFormatter = new System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter();
        binaryFormatter.Serialize(memoryStream, o);
        return memoryStream.ToArray();
    }
    return null;
}

//de-serialization
public static object convertByteArrToObject(byte[] b)
{
    if (b != null && b.Length > 0)
    {
        System.IO.MemoryStream memoryStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(b);
        System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter binaryFormatter = new System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter();
        memoryStream.Position = 0;
        return binaryFormatter.Deserialize(memoryStream);

    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: What is the exception?

Comment: Sorry for the slow response: it's {"Unable to load type Authentication.User required for deserialization."}

Answer (score 5):

Do not store binary serialized objects in the database. Serialize user as its properties into tables, using your ORM of choice (EF, Linq2SQL, NHibernate etc).

Serializing *binary* objects into database is incredibly bad. Databases are long lived and queryable. You are negating both in one stroke: your long lived data can onyl be deserialized by the very specific code you have now (20 years from now someone will have to run C# v. 4.5 to desrialize your objects stored today) and the binary serialized object is nothing but an opaque blob to the database, unqueryable and unsearchable.

Don't do it.

Comment: We're using NHibernate anyway. Can you elaborate more on `Serialize user as its properties into tables` ? 

The idea behind storing user as binary serialized obj is to save the time to construct the object (actual User contain many more properties, my code is just a simplified example)

Comment: In the example above you would have a table `Users` with an ID and a field `Name`. NHibernate knows how to serialize/deserialize into this.

Comment: `save the time to construct the object` you are throwing away the child with the bathwater. I highly doubt that this optimization is necessary to start with (even for a very complex object) and the side effects of your decision are devastating.

Comment: Think at this: can another project use Java to read your Users if they are serialized binary C#? Or Ruby or Python or whatever. Your objects in teh database are C#, for ever and ever.

Comment: I'm going to raise a point about terminology: the problem isn't the fact that it is "binary" - the problem is the fact that it is based entirely on type metadata. There are binary storage formats that will work fine in the future against different types in a different language on a different platform. Avro, protobuf, thrift, ice, etc.

Comment: @MarcGravell: I would oppose just as strongly storing protobuf, avro, thrift or any other opaque blob in the database. Unless you are talking about a specific engine designed to handle exactly that format (eg. JSON serialization stored on Mongo), you are transforming the DB into a file storage and there is no point to it. The scenarios where storing objects as BLOBs actually makes sense are very narrow, specific, scenarios.

Comment: To give an example when serializing blobs makes sense: a queue (Redis?) where the object lives in the DB for seconds/minutes/days. Basically when the long term storage of the data is taken out of the equation.

Comment: @MarcGravell: the exception I'm facing is due to missing definition of old namespace. Is there anyway to instruct the de-serialization process to use new namespace and new metadata?

Comment: @RemusRusanu I'm going to disagree with you there; yes, tabular is preferable, but sometimes it is fine to store opaque data - and binary formats are perfectly valid there

Comment: @DioPhung there are things you can do with "custom binders", but frankly `BinaryFormatter` is a huge mess here; I do not recommend using `BinaryFormatter`... well, ever, actually.

Comment: s it best practice NOT to store binary object in database ? The problem I am trying to solve here is how to deserialize when the serialized object to new namespace ?

Answer (score 0):

I would make the case that there are some valid cases for storing binary data in a database.  For example, in our commercial product, the database is used to store data internally, so we use a binary serialized form to make it *intentionally* unqueryable and unsearchable.  We include an indexed key column along with the binary data column for lookup, but beyond that the data is unrecognizable.

There is an added benefit that the binary serialized data takes less storage space than if we created a column for every field in the object.

We use [version tolerant serialization (VTS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/version-tolerant-serialization) to address the updated code issue, but not sure this helps with the original post where the namespace has changed.